# How can I map data of multiple collections in snapshot?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am not too confident working with Firestore and have trouble with more complex API calls to get data. Usually I use SQL backends in my apps.

For the section that I am working on, I would like to combine three collections to get an array of *ToDos* with the involved *users* and the *category* the current user labelled this ToDo with. Every involved person can label the ToDo like they prefer, which makes things a little more complicated. Broken down the collections are structured as follows.

**todo:** Firestore Database Document

```js
{
   title: string,
   involved: string[], //user ids
   involvedCategory: string[] //category ids mapped by index to involved
}
```

(I tried to have an array of objects here instead of the two arrays, but it seems I would not be able to query the array for the  current user´s ID, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351321/how-to-query-documents-containing-array-of-objects-in-firestore-collection-using), so this is a workaround)

**category:** Firestore Database Document

```js
{
   title: string,
   color: string
}
```

**user:** Firebase Authentication User

```js
{
   uid: string,
   displayName: string,
   photoURL: string,
   ...
}
```

**THE GOAL**
An array of ToDo items like this:

```js
{
   id: string,
   title: string,
   involved: User[],
   category?: {
      title: string,
      color: string
   }
}
```

As I am working with TypeScript, I created an interface to use a converter with. My code looks like this so far:

```js
import {
    DocumentData,
    FirestoreDataConverter,
    WithFieldValue,
    QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    SnapshotOptions,
    query,
    collection,
    where,
} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { store } from '../firebase'
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore'
import { User } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useCategories } from './categories'
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext'

interface ToDo {
    id: string
    title: string
    involved: User[]
    category?: {
        title: string
        color: string
    }
}

const converter: FirestoreDataConverter<ToDo> = {
    toFirestore(todo: WithFieldValue<ToDo>): DocumentData {
        return {} //not implemented yet
    },
    fromFirestore(
        snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot,
        options: SnapshotOptions
    ): ToDo {
        const data = snapshot.data(options)

        return {
            id: snapshot.id,
            title: data.title,
            category: undefined, //?
            involved: [], //?
        }
    },
}

export function useToDos() {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    const { categories } = useCategories() //needed in converter

    const ref = query(
        collection(store, 'habits'),
        where('involved', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid)
    ).withConverter(converter)
    const [data] = useCollectionData(ref)

    return {
        todos: data,
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can do this? I have a Hook that returns all of the user´s categories, but I obviously can´t call that outside the
`useToDos`-Hook. And creating the const in the hook does not help, either, as it results in an infinite re-render.

I know this is a long one, but does anyone have tips how I could approach this? Thanks in advance ^^

**UPDATE:**
I had to make two small adjustments to @ErnestoC ´s solution in case anyone is doing something similar:

First, I changed the calls for `currentUser.id` to `currentUser.uid`.

Afterwards I got the very missleading `Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions`, which made me experiment a lot with my security rules. But that is not where the error originated. Debugging the code line by line, I noticed the category objects resolved by the promise where not correct and had a weird path with multiple spaces at the beginning and the end of their ids. When I removed them before saving them in the `promises` array, it worked. Although I do not see where the spaces came from in the first place.

```js
promises.push(
    getDoc(
        doc(
             store,
             'categories',
             docSnap.data().involvedCategory[userCatIndex].replaceAll(' ', '')
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach, given that Firestore is a NoSQL database that [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56611064/16929894) server-side JOINS, is to perform all the data combinations on the client side or in the backend with a Cloud Function.

For your scenario, one approach is to first query the `ToDo` documents by the array membership of the current user's ID in the `involved` array.

Afterwards, you fetch the corresponding category document the current user assigned to that `ToDo` (going by index mapping between the two arrays). Finally, you should be able to construct your `ToDo` objects with the data.

```js
const toDoArray = [];
const promises = [];

//Querying the ToDo collection
const q = query(collection(firestoreDB, 'habits'), where('involved', 'array-contains', currentUser.id));
const querySnap = await getDocs(q);

querySnap.forEach((docSnap) => {
  //Uses index mapping 
  const userCatIndex = docSnap.data().involved.indexOf(currentUser.id);
  //For each matching ToDo, get the corresponding category from the categories collection
  promises.push(getDoc(doc(firestoreDB, 'categories', docSnap.data().involvedCategory[userCatIndex])));
  //Pushes object to ToDo class/interface
  toDoArray.push(new ToDo(docSnap.id, docSnap.data().title, docSnap.data().involved))
});

//Resolves all promises of category documents, then adds the data to the existing ToDo objects.
await Promise.all(promises).then(categoryDocs => {
  categoryDocs.forEach((userCategory, i) => {
    toDoArray[i].category = userCategory.data();
  });  
});
console.log(toDoArray);
```

Using the `FirestoreDataConverter` interface would not be that different, as you would need to still perform an additional query for the `category` data, and then add the data to your custom objects. Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: @Bexy-Lyn did you need more help in combining your Firestore collections?

Comment: I get an `Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined` in the 3rd line of code. I will work on that a bit more.

Comment: Okay I made it work. Thanks Ernesto :) For anyone who wants to do something similar: See my edit.